# CollectionView datasource and delegate methods not being called

Tags: swift

The UICollectionView's datasource and delegate methods are not being called. I have

```
class MessagesViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
 @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
 override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  self.collectionView.dataSource = self
  self.collectionView.delegate = self
```

And the function

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
```

is not being called.

Comment: did you implement `collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:`?

Comment: Yes. I used the exact line in my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't write a comment because of low reputation, but my guess would be that you set the dataSource and delegate in the viewDidLoad() method. Perhaps hook the dataSource and delegate up in the storyboard by control-dragging from your CollectionView to the ViewController containing it. You could also try reloading the collectionView data with collectionView.reloadData() after you set the dataSource and delegate in viewDidLoad().

Answer (score 0):

SWIFT 3 - In swift 3 the delegate methods are little bit changed. I faced the same issue because of these changes. Please find the correct delegate methods

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    //Do here
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath:IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
   //Do here
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

  //Do here
}
```